# Unable to add custom matchers to jasmine (karma)

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Jasmine is working and the unit tests execute but I can't add my own matchers to jasmine.

```
ReferenceError: mymatch is not defined
```

this is how I try to add them:

```
it('all values are zero', function () {

 jasmine.addMatchers({
        mymatch: function () {
            return {
                compare: function (actual, expected) {
                   return {
                   pass: (actual % 2) === 0
                      };
                   }
               };
           }
        });

expect(mymatch(0, 0));

});
```

I tried also to add them in a beforeEach function (both: inside a test-suite and at the very beginning of the file)

Am I missing some dependencies here? Or could there be a conflict (I have the node modules locally installed but also some globally installed packages (ubuntu14.04)

from my karma.conf.js:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine'],
```

from my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "karma": "~0.12.24",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.5",
   "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.2",
   "package.json": "~0.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "karma": "~0.12.24",
   "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.2"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I used the matchers the wrong way,

```
NOT: expect(mymatch(0, 0));
```

they must be used like this:

```
expect(0).mymatch( 0);
```